# command line with mv - file disappeared?

Tags: bash

Folks, I have a bunch of files compressed with gzip like so:

```
    ...
la.20110208.gz
va.20110208.gz
la.20110209.gz
va.20110209.gz
    ...
```

I typed by accident the following command

```
mv la.20110209* <enter>
```

while I meant to type

```
mv la.20110209* /docs_backup/<enter>
```

Now I cannot find my file: only `va.20110209.gz` remains. Any idea where `la.20110209.gz` went? I'm on Ubuntu, running bash shell....

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there were exactly two *files* that matched that pattern, I'm afraid that you will have lost one of them.  When you type:

```
mv *20110209*
```

... bash tries to expand those wildcards before running `mv`, so what `mv` would see if just those two files matched is:

```
mv blahblah.20110209-b.gz blahblah.20110209.gz
```

So `blahblah.20110209.gz` would have been overwritten by `blahblah.20110209-b.gz`.  If there were more than two files that matched then you would get the error:

```
mv: target `blahblah.20110209.gz' is not a directory
```

The best case would be if `*20110209*` expanded to a list of files and a directory as the last item, in which case they'd all be moved into that directory.  However, it sounds as if this was the first case I mentioned.

(Some people like to alias `mv` to `mv -i` for this kind of reason.)

Comment: you eloquently explained what I was afraid of. ((Hanging head in shame))

Comment: @Chris: Bad luck :(  This is unfortunately all too easy to do by accident.

Comment: Cursed fat fingers of mine.... There should be a thread titled "your worst *nix mistake": that would be my contrib.

Comment: I actually had an alias which had a similar effect to mv -f, so I managed to wipe out (almost; there were backups) a whole directory by typing mv * ../foo where foo did not exist.

Answer (score 3):

When you typed `mv *20010209*` your shell performed *pathname expansion* on that such that the `mv` command saw the following arguments:

```
mv la.20110208.gz va.20110208.gz ... la.20110209.gz last_file
```

If `last_file` just so happens to be a directory, then all the files listed before it will be moved into there.  Unless you only have 2 files that matched, this must be what have happened because you would have received an error from `mv` otherwise.

Look for a directory that matches `*20010209*` via the following command, that is where you files will be:

```
find . -type d -name "*20010209*"
```

Comment: Well, typing `echo mv *20110209*` simply echoes `mv *20110209*`. Nothing else. What am I missing?

Comment: find() returns only one file matching the pattern. !@#%$. Okay. I'll contact my sysadmin.